# EntityFramework - Custom Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a custom type that is stored as a `FLOAT` in the database. Currently the models where this property needs to be exposed are doing so using `double`, so it can be mapped and queried. Is it possible to tell entity framework how to treat a custom type?

For example:

```
public struct MyType {
    public double ActualValue { get; set; }
}
```

being used as:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyType MyType { get; set; }
}
```

I know you can map `MyType.ActualValue` to a column, but that does not allow it to be queried.

Comment: Have you considered using a different type to load the data from EF and mapping that to your model?

Comment: I have considered that, I just wondered whether there was an alternative?